# Every infinite set is $T$- infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the claim in the title as stated in the Set theory book by Thomas Jech.

As for the definitions:

> A set $X$ has $n$ elements (where $n\in \mathbb{N}$) if there is a one-one mapping of $n$ onto $X$. A set is finite if it has $n$ elements for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and infinite if not.
>
> A set $S$ is $T$-finite if every nonempty $X\subset P(S)$ has a $\subset$-maximal element, i.e. $u\in X$ s.t there's no $v\in X$ with $u\subset v$ and $u\ne v$. $S$ is $T$ infinite if it's not $T$-finite.

So as a hint I am given the following:
"If $S$ is infinite, consider $X = \{ u\subset S: u \ is \ finite \}$".
So obviously $\emptyset \ne X \subset \mathbb{P}(S)$; I need now to show that for every $u\in X$ there exists $v\in X$ s.t $v\ne u$ and $u\subset v$, this will prove that $S$ is $T$-infinite.

But how to show this?, I thought of taking $v = u \cup \{ u\}$ but I am not sure if it's a subset of $S$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u$ is finite and $S$ is not, $u\ne S$. But certainly $u\subseteq S$ so there must be an $a\in S\setminus u$.

Now consider $u\cup\{a\}$.

Comment: How can $u$ be a subset of $X$ if it belongs by $\in$-membership to $X$?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: Whoops, that was a typo. All of my $X$ should have been $S$.

Comment: Thanks, I see it's easy, should have seen it.